# Can consecutive numbers form a palindrome?

Tags: mathematics

Consider a number formed by concatenating all the natural numbers from $1$ to $n$, for some $n>1$.

(E.g. with $n=13$ this number would be $12345678910111213$.)

### **Is it possible for such a number to be a palindrome?**

Please provide either an example or a proof of impossibility.

<sub><sub>I found this puzzle in the 1996 All-Russian Mathematical Olympiad.</sub></sub>

Comment: Well, I know of *one* example...

Comment: @A.Mirabeau Edited to exclude the trivial case :-)

Comment: Hm, this puzzle seems familiar... :P

Comment: @Deusovi It does, but I can't remember where I've seen it before! I tried searching on the site for "consecutive" or "palindrome", but couldn't find it anywhere, so I'm hoping it's not a dupe.

Comment: @randal'thor: It was here, but deleted for plagiarism (without citing any source).

Comment: Ahhhh, that explains the sense of familiarity I too had about it.

Comment: Note that a palindromic concatenation of numbers is not necessarily impossible in all *bases*; for instance, in binary, *n* = 3 quite happily produces the palindrome 0b11011.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266124

Comment: The proof in the accepted answer there is very nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm sure I saw almost exactly this question somewhere in the last week or thereabouts. Maybe my brain's playing tricks. I don't think I read the 1996 All-Russian Mathematical Olympiad recently. Perhaps there was another question about concatenated consecutive numbers.)

The answer is that

> it is not possible.

Why?

> Suppose $n$ has $k$ digits. By inspection $k>1$. Let $m$ consist of the last $k-1$ digits of $n$; then the end of our monstrous number looks like $k-1$ 9s, then the first digit of $n$, then $k-1$ 0s, then another $km$ digits. Therefore its start looks like the reverse of that: $km$ digits, then $k-1$ 0s, then the first digit of $n$, then $k-1$ 9s.

But

> this can't happen. That string of $k-1$ zeros after the first $km$ digits can't include the first digit of any of the constituent numbers making up the monstrous number, so they are in fact the final $k-1$ digits of a $k$-digit number. But then they cannot possibly be followed by a single digit and then $k-1$ 9s; rather, they must be followed by a single digit, $k-2$ 0s, and a single 1. Contradiction.

Comment: Sniped! Was working on it this whole time!

Comment: Sorry! I think I happened to see it very soon after it was posted.

Comment: Out of curiosity (I know this wasn't part of the question), for which bases other than 10 would this proof work? @A.Mirabeau noticed that palindromic concatentaion is possible in binary, for example; is it possible in ternary or any higher bases?

Comment: I think it works in any base higher than binary.

Comment: The last three digits have to be $321$, not what you say. The approach is good. The largest block of zeros cannot be mirrored earlier

Comment: Did you miss the "another km digits" part of my description of how the number ends? (It's true that the last digits have to be 321, but that doesn't contradict what I said.)

Answer (score 4):

I have checked your question, and you do not say it must be in base 10. Maybe my assumtion is wrong.

> Yes it always happen in base 1
>  1,2 base 10 = 1,11 base 1
>  Concatenate it will become 111

Comment: OK, you found an unintended loophole :-) Base 10 was supposed to be an unspoken assumption, but I have to admit this is a kinda-sorta valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> No, except for maybe a few small base examples, e.g. $b=2,n=3:\;11011_2$

Because:

> Consider the final integer in such a number. Let's assume $b=10$. Let's say it is $4131211101987654321$. The number that precedes this is $4131211101987654320$, which ends in a $20$ making continuity impossible as the theoretical last number would have to start with a number needing a $0$, then a $2$, then a $3$, and so on. The next number would have to end in a number needing a $19$, but the most significant digits of the number won't have changed. For an example, the last few digits are now $41312111019876543204131211101987654321$.

Comment: "*making continuity impossible as the next number would have to start with a 0*" - I don't understand this bit. What if the final integer $n$ is something like 1987654321? Then $n-1$ ending in a $0$ is perfectly valid from the point of view of palindromicity. (Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean?)